# Python, Selenium : 'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I am scraping a website, [www.lipperleaders.com](http://www.lipperleaders.com/). I want to extract the funds detail of Singapore. I have successfully implemented drop-down selection and extracted the content of the first page appearing after submission of the options. But when I try to go to next pages (by making the code to click next button) I am getting error `'Element is no longer attached to the DOM'`.

My code is about 100 lines but I can give a general idea of the flow of execution of my code:

```
...                    # creating driver object and all the imports
def main():
    ...
    result = find_elements_by_tag_name('span')  
    ...
    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucDataPager_btnNext").click()
    main()
main()
```

This code works fine for the 1st page but when `main()` is called again after clicking of the next button. Before this recursive method, I also tried putting this inside a loop, then also same error.

And if I write the same code like:

```
# some code
result = find_elements_by_tag_name('span')  
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucDataPager_btnNext").click()
# some code
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ucDataPager_btnNext").click()
.
.
```

This code works fine w/o any error the next page loads and executes the code written after that. But I cannot write the  same `driver.find_element_by_id().click()` for 500 pages, even I will have to repeat the rest of the code associated with each page. That's why I am trying for loop or recursion, but its not working for me.

Please let me know what is the problem with my approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the element is being detached by some javascript. So you should make the driver wait for the element: This is done by setting `implicitly_wait`, see:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
...
myDynamicElement = ff.find_element_by_id("myDynamicElement")
```

from 
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits

Comment: that worked but now I am getting new error `'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up'`

Comment: You would need to search for the element in each iteration step of your loop. so in each iteration you do something like `next_button = driver.find_element_by_id('btnNextId') next_btn.click()`

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i am doing after each iteration clicking the next button to move to next page, but then also it is showing `Element not found in the cache..`. I cleared the cache of firefox then it crawled 5-6 pages and then again gave this error.

Comment: Hmm this is really strange... Then you might want to start your driver with no cache as of here:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=40

Comment: @Vipul did you find any solution? I am getting the same problem "Element not found in the cache..."

Comment: @InêsMartins The link given by ProfHase85 was pretty helpful see here: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/40 start the driver with no cache

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is an stale element exception generally it occurs when you try to find some element. `Which gets loaded every time but you found it earlier`, so this is a stale.

I'll suggest to use some customized method to avoid this, One of the simplest solution:

```
void clickOnStaleElement(String id, WebDriver driver) {
    try {
        driver.find_element_by_id(id).click();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        // Trying to find element stale element
        clickOnStaleElement(id, driver);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ele) {
        clickOnStaleElement(id, driver);
    }
 }
```